# How programmatically dock new element to DockPanel

Tags: wpf, user-controls, dockpanel

How programmatically create an element based on UserControl and dock it to the DockPanel?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
var myControl = new MyUserControl();
DockPanel.SetDock(myControl, Dock.Left);
myDockPanel.Children.Add(myControl);
```

Also see [here](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/Resources/Detail.aspx?ResourceId=655) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.setdock.aspx).

Comment: Any ideas as to why the app would be unresponsive after adding a usercontrol to a dockpanel?

Comment: @IAbstract, no that should not happen.

Comment: I actually figured this out - incorrect URI. :( Seems like this could be more gracefully handled. As soon as you inquire a property of the image, it just freezes.

Answer (score 3):

```
Button TopRect = new Button();

TopRect.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGreen);

TopRect.Height = 50;

TopRect.Content = "Top";

// Dock button to top

DockPanel.SetDock(TopRect, Dock.Top);

// Add docked button to DockPanel

dcPanel.Children.Add(TopRect);
```

[Example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Resources/Detail.aspx?ResourceId=655)

Answer (score 2):

```
var uc = new UserControl1();
uc.SetValue(DockPanel.DockProperty, Dock.Left);
myDockPanel.Children.Add(uc);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your DockPanel's last element is floating in the middle of the panel, check that you've assigned `myDockPanel.LastChildFill = false;`